# Typo3 fe_user get user with specific group only

Tags: php, typo3, query-builder, extbase

I have a website with a frontend login. Each user assigned a specific usergroup. In order to set the order of user group I extended fe_groups and added a new field order. For example, there are three groups grouplevel1, grouplevel2, greouplevel3 have the order 1,2,3 respectively. the model of fe_group is below

```
class UserGroup extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUserGroup
{
    /**
     * order
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $order = null;


    /**
     * Returns the order
     *
     * @return int order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the order
     *
     * 
     * @param int order
     * @return void
     */
    public function setOrder(int $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

}
```

In my system users are initially in the group grouplevel1, after some time the user gets group grouplevel2 and grouplevel3.   I need to filter the users in grouplevel1. When I try to call my function it returns users with all the 3 groups. I need to filter the user with only one group. How to write the repository method? I tried with the following query but it doesn't meet my requirement.

```
public function getFilteredList($groups){
   $query = $this->createQuery();
   $constraints = [];
   $userGroupArray = array_map('intval', $groups);
   $constraints[] = $query->in('usergroup', $userGroupArray);
   $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints));
   return $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: is there a way you can get the uid of the group? Because in this function you pass all the groups as parameter and then you re using the 'in' statement which searches for all user in the groups with the given uids. Multiple uids

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas   What is the solution?

Comment: is there a way you can get the uid of the group? Or one group?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas the variable $group is an array which contain the uid of group

Comment: yes but contains all the groups. You need to get only the group id you want to search for. How do you call the getFilteredList function in your controller?

Comment: not contains all the group. Only the uid of group which is searched

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206777/discussion-between-aswathy-s-and-aristeidis-karavas).